# CocoaPods beta versions

Tags: ios, sdk, cocoapods, opentok, podspec

I'm building a project with a CocoaPods component for OpenTok (iOS WebRTC SDK) and they've released a beta version but they have no intention to add this as a spec for beta testing with it.

My question is about making a spec for that beta version. So, I've made a fork of the project and added a tag '2.2beta' for pointing to it from the spec, but I don't know if it's right to make the spec pointing to my fork or if I need to make a pull request to the original repository and wait for it to be accepted to make a new spec?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a discussion with @Orta from the Cocoapods team, the answer was NO.

After CocoaPods adopted the new Trunk web service, the rules changed for publishing a new PodSpec:

> The introduction of the ‘Trunk’ web-service means that publishers can
>   now publish Pods directly from the command-line, without the need to
>   create a pull-request.  From http://blog.cocoapods.org/CocoaPods-Trunk/

So, the creator of the pod and the mantainers that the owner gives his blessing to, are the only who can push new PodSpecs.

The workaround for this, is to ask the owners of the pod (OpenTok for my particular case) to include the beta version as a new PodSpec or to include me as a "blessed" contributor for using the new Trunk web service to add it by myself.

Comment: Developer at TokBox (creators of OpenTok) here. Thanks for the interest @Floydian. We've claimed ownership of the two pods on CocoaPods Trunk and do intend to use if for official distribution in the future. As for betas, we still recommend you incorporate OpenTok.framework into your project manually, since we don't plan on releasing them on CocoaPods. When v2.2 stable is released, it will all be seamless.